# XGBoost on GPU throws memory allocation error for tiny memory request

Tags: python, xgboost

I'm attempting to run XGBoost 1.6.1 through the Python `scikit-learn` interface on an NVIDIA Tesla K80 GPU using CUDA Toolkit 11.3. The following example code throws a memory allocation error, even though the GPU has plenty of memory available.

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_wine
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X, y = load_wine(return_X_y=True, as_frame=True)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,
                                                    y,
                                                    test_size=0.30,
                                                    random_state=0)
classifier = XGBClassifier(tree_method='gpu_hist')
model = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

And the traceback (relative paths given for privacy reasons):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/.config/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2022.1/scratches/scratch.py", line 11, in <module>
    model = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "~/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 532, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)
  File "~/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/sklearn.py", line 1400, in fit
    self._Booster = train(
  File "~/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 532, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)
  File "~/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/training.py", line 181, in train
    bst.update(dtrain, i, obj)
  File "~/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 1733, in update
    _check_call(_LIB.XGBoosterUpdateOneIter(self.handle,
  File "~/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/core.py", line 203, in _check_call
    raise XGBoostError(py_str(_LIB.XGBGetLastError()))
xgboost.core.XGBoostError: [07:31:30] ../src/c_api/../data/../common/device_helpers.cuh:428: Memory allocation error on worker 0: [07:31:30] ../src/c_api/../data/../common/common.h:46: ../src/common/device_helpers.cuh: 447: cudaErrorNoKernelImageForDevice: no kernel image is available for execution on the device
Stack trace:
  [bt] (0) ~/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x38f939) [0x7f363eb54939]
  [bt] (1) ~/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x3938d3) [0x7f363eb588d3]
  [bt] (2) ~/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x3d39ae) [0x7f363eb989ae]
  [bt] (3) ~/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x3e7914) [0x7f363ebac914]
  [bt] (4) ~/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x3e9790) [0x7f363ebae790]
  [bt] (5) ~/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x57d309) [0x7f363ed42309]
  [bt] (6) ~/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x20fca8) [0x7f363e9d4ca8]
  [bt] (7) ~/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(XGBoosterUpdateOneIter+0x68) [0x7f363e86e688]
  [bt] (8) /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6(ffi_call_unix64+0x4c) [0x7f36797b08ee]


- Free memory: 11841830912
- Requested memory: 496

Stack trace:
  [bt] (0) ~/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x38f939) [0x7f363eb54939]
  [bt] (1) ~/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x393d4b) [0x7f363eb58d4b]
  [bt] (2) ~/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x3d3ae9) [0x7f363eb98ae9]
  [bt] (3) ~/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x3e7914) [0x7f363ebac914]
  [bt] (4) ~/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x3e9790) [0x7f363ebae790]
  [bt] (5) ~/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x57d309) [0x7f363ed42309]
  [bt] (6) ~/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x20fca8) [0x7f363e9d4ca8]
  [bt] (7) ~/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(XGBoosterUpdateOneIter+0x68) [0x7f363e86e688]
  [bt] (8) /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6(ffi_call_unix64+0x4c) [0x7f36797b08ee]



Process finished with exit code 1
```

As you can see, the free memory far exceeds the requested memory. Running in `compute-sanitizer` gives a massive output, but I think the relevant part is extracted here:

```
> cat sanitizer.out | grep Program
========= Program hit invalid device function (error 98) on CUDA API call to cudaFuncGetAttributes.
========= Program hit invalid device function (error 98) on CUDA API call to cudaGetLastError.
========= Program hit no kernel image is available for execution on the device (error 209) on CUDA API call to cudaLaunchKernel.
========= Program hit no kernel image is available for execution on the device (error 209) on CUDA API call to cudaPeekAtLastError.
========= Program hit no kernel image is available for execution on the device (error 209) on CUDA API call to cudaPeekAtLastError.
========= Program hit no kernel image is available for execution on the device (error 209) on CUDA API call to cudaGetLastError.
========= Program hit no kernel image is available for execution on the device (error 209) on CUDA API call to cudaLaunchKernel.
========= Program hit no kernel image is available for execution on the device (error 209) on CUDA API call to cudaGetLastError.
```

Any clues please?

Comment: "no kernel image is available for execution on the device" -- the version of whatever is it you are using hasn't been built with compute capability 3.7 support, i.e. it doesn't support your GPU

Comment: Could you be more specific? xgboost is a very widely used package, I’d be surprised if it doesn’t support the K80.

Comment: I have been as specific as possible. You have a runtime error because there is no binary support för your GPU in the package. It is right there in the output in you posted in your question. You can choose to accept it or not.

Comment: xgboost 1.6.1 supports compute capability >=3.5 per the docs: https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gpu/index.html#:~:text=The%20GPU%20algorithms%20in%20XGBoost,CUDA%20toolkits%2010.1%20or%20later.

Comment: "Supporting" and "being build with that support" are two different things. The version of xgboost that you have installed lacks binary support for your GPU. The CUDA runtime error confirms that, whether you like it or not. It has been very common for frameworks to strip support from old architectures to save space (Tensorflow and PyTorch do this). The K80 GPU you are using is deprecated as of the CUDA 11.0 release and all support is slated for removal in the next major release cycle. That likely has some bearing on the lack of support in the binary build of xgboost you are using.

Comment: Well, I asked for "any clues", and this turned out to be a clue if not a full answer. The response from the XGBoost maintainers is posted as an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

From the [XGBoost discussion list](https://discuss.xgboost.ai/t/no-kernel-image-for-tesla-k80-on-xgboost-1-6-1/2828/4)

> @hcho3
> You will need to install XGBoost from the source if you intend to use an old card. The usual method of install (pip) only supports 5.2 and up. Let me update the install doc to indicate this.